# Count similar values from table by combining two tables

Tags: sql, oracle, count, oracle9i

I have two table

```
table A
name id 
ABC  1
PQR  2
XYZ  1
QWE  2
DFG  3
```

Another table
table B

```
id idname
1   stuart
2   bob
3   alex
```

expected output

```
id idname count
1  stuart 2
2  bob     2
3  alex   1
```

Iam using oracle 9i, Is it possible to obtain the expected result?
I have tried using distinct keyword but its not helping as it provides only the total count

Comment: What are you counting?

Comment: JOIN the tables. Do a GROUP BY.

Comment: `select b.id, b.idname, count(a.id) from tableB b left join tableA a group by b.id, b.idname`

Comment: @jarlh Iam trying to get the count as in count of occurrence of 1 , 2 , 3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's simple. `Join` and `count`:

```
select b.id, 
    b.idname,
    count(*) as cnt
from table_a a
join table_b b on a.id = b.id
group by b.id, b.idname;
```

If you need all the record from table b even if there is no corresponding row in table a, you can use an outer join:

```
select b.id, 
    b.idname,
    count(a.id) as cnt
from table_a a
right join table_b b on a.id = b.id
group by b.id, b.idname;
```

Same can be achieved by using a left join:

```
select b.id, 
    b.idname,
    count(a.id) as cnt
from table_b b
left join table_a a on a.id = b.id
group by b.id, b.idname;
```

Comment: I would use `RIGHT JOIN` and alter `count` to include zero count

Comment: RIGHT JOIN... Switch table order and do LEFT JOIN instead. (Too many people find right join too confusing. It's much easier to get "main table left join optional data" instead of "optional data right join main table".)

Comment: Thanks a lot for help God bless you :)

Comment: Agree with @jarlh, a right join is just a left join written backwards. Why not `from table_b b left join table_a a on a.id = b.id`?

Comment: @WilliamRobertson - There. Updated.:)

Answer (score 0):

Use `JOIN` to get data from both tables and use the aggregate function `COUNT` with `GROUP BY`.

**Query**

```
select t1.id, t1.idname, count(t2.name) as count
from TableB t1
left join TableA t2
on t1.id = t2.id
group by t1.id, t1.idname
order by count(t2.name) desc, t1.id;;
```

Comment: I would use `LEFT JOIN` and to include zero count

Comment: Why don't you use the column alias in the ORDER BY? I.e. `order by count desc, t1.id`.

Comment: Thanks a lot for help... God bless you :)